# How Can I Get My Dog to Relax In the Car Again?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog has never been as gung-ho in the car as my last dog who sadly died of cancer much too young. The faster you went the happier she was. But I digress...I was driving with my dog, Bear, around Christmastime and someone stopped extremely suddenly ahead of us. I had to slam on the brakes to keep from hitting them. But, in doing so, he went off the backseat onto the floor and sort of bounced off the back of the passenger seat.
Ever since that happened, he hasn't been comfortable in the car. He just about starts whining the minute we get in the car and for most of our rides. I love driving around in the car so it can get annoying. No incidents have occurred since that one. No really sudden stops, swerves or anything of the kind. Yet, he's still whining and crying in the car on every ride. Is there any way to get him to feel safe, comfortable and relaxed in the car again? I have a 900-mile trip down to Georgia planned in October where we're driving. It will be a very long trip with him whining and crying all the way down.

Comment: Did the dog have an own belt? Or this kind of blanket you place at the head-parts of front seats and back seats so it becomes a kind of hammock? It will not help with the whining in first place, but it would help the safety and that the bad memory will not happen again